# Safari - "input search" causing viewport pushing to left

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I'll make this as short as I possible can.

I built a PWA. When clicking on the search icon it will slide to left - no problems.

I'm using a search feature which is containing "input search".

Every browser I have tested, the input group is not causing any issues for me.

When you go on safari on the other hand, you can click on the search icon the first time, and it will then display the search as normal. When you close it, no problems.. But click on it again, then close it again, you'll see that the website/viewport is pushed to the left. Test it on https://logima.io **(on safari web browser)** just to see the actual problem by hand.

I have tried relative, absolute, fixed and all sorts of box-sizing for different browsers.

I have spent 7 hours debugging the problem, and it definitely comes down to:

```
    <input
      ref="search"
      id="search"
      v-model="search"
      @input="makeSearch"
      class="search-panel-input"
      :placeholder="$t('Type what you are looking for...')"
      type="text"
      autofocus="true"
    >
```

But, it has nothing to do with the parameters which represents any styling or functions. It has solely to do with "input" itself.

I bought a brand new Macbook Air with 8GB Memory just 3 days ago and developer tools on safari is so slow I can not even use it at all, so I can't quickly debug the problem on developer tools there either which leads me here.

This can possibly be a result of another CSS code i've created causing this to clash. I am trying to figure out a way to make my viewport to not get pushed to left no matter what.

This is not the most critical issue as the search is displayed as I intend it to do on all browsers, on first time usage. But Safari is causing input to push viewport to left on second usage, and that is annoying yet an interesting issue to solve.

I will try myself to debug this styling issue but I'm reaching out here as I am positive there are some web designers more qualified than me to speak on styling in safari.

Any contributions to solving this issue is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it seems to be caused by the `div`(s) in your footer with class `row`.

[image]

So far, I've been able to address the issue by:

- Setting `margin-left/right` to `0px` (rather than -15px)
- Disabling the values in Dev Tools
- Removing the elements entirely from the DOM

(All done before opening the Search Panel)

Comment: Thank you! Haha you know what, it was a SVG element sticking out of the footer. For some reason in safari the SVG element is not sized properly, but in other browsers there's no problem. But without your help I think I could've gone longer as I'd never expect the problem coming from the footer in safari.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, after I created media queries for sizing the SVG which was creating huge space in mobile view on safari, there was still the gap which you pointed out. I adjusted the margins to 0px and solved it, thanks again!

Comment: @KristopherHendricks No problem, glad we could tackle the issue together! It was my first time seeing/experiencing a bug like that and was nice to learn something new! :)